# Issue with sonarqube analysis

Tags: sonarqube

Iam using sonarqube Version 5.0.1 along with sonar-ant-task-2.3.jar to analyse java source code. 
My setup is working for many projects but for one project alone iam getting following error:

> Caused by: com.persistit.exception.ConversionException: Requested
>   size=67108916 exceeds maximum size=67108864   at
>   com.persistit.Value.ensureFit(Value.java:784)     at
>   com.persistit.Value.putCharSequenceInternal(Value.java:5411)  at
>   com.persistit.Value.putUTF(Value.java:3518)   at
>   org.sonar.batch.duplication.DuplicationBlockValueCoder.put(DuplicationBlockValueCoder.java:32)
>     at
>   org.sonar.batch.duplication.DuplicationGroupValueCoder.put(DuplicationGroupValueCoder.java:41)
>     at com.persistit.Value.put(Value.java:3453)     at
>   com.persistit.encoding.CollectionValueCoder.put(CollectionValueCoder.java:126)
>     at com.persistit.Value.put(Value.java:3453)     at
>   com.persistit.Value.put(Value.java:3255)  at
>   org.sonar.batch.index.Cache.doPut(Cache.java:72)  ... 57 more

Total time: 112 minutes 14 seconds
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Can anyone please help me to fix the issue...

Answer (score 0):

This issue is referenced by https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6000 and is fixed in versions 4.5.4 and 5.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But is there any thing that i could do to fix the issue without upgrading/downgrading the sonar?

Comment: Not really, except decreasing the number of duplications on your project.